# Does the request has been redirected?

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL via PHP, I need to understand If the request has been redirected during the process.

I have set **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** option to true using **curl_setopt()**.

Now, if I request `example.com/page.php` how can I understand if the page change the **Location:** without parsing the header of the response manually?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, make a HEAD request instead and check if the response status code is a redirect (301, 302, 303, 305 and 307 are redirect codes)

A head request is achieved with `CURLOPT_NOBODY`

The status code can be checked with `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

**Update**

I found a simpler solution if you need the response of the actual redirected page:

```
if (curl_getinfo($ch,  CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT) > 0) {
    // redirected
}
```

So you can follow redirects and determine if there were any afterwards.